# MySQL: Count rows between two timestamps for each day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table where I save the subscribers of my newsletter like this:

```
mail    |subscribed|unsubscribed
--------|----------|------------
a@b.com |2016-01-29|0000-00-00
q@q.net |2016-06-08|2016-08-08
r@r.org |2016-04-25|2016-08-01
```

Now I want to create a graph where I can see how many subscribers I had on each day.

The only way I see at the moment is to execute that query **one time for each day** like this (where "Date" is each date):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM newsletter WHERE subscribed < "Date" AND (unsubscribed > "Date" OR unsubscribed = 0)
```

Is there a query I only have to call once and for every day in the year?

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: @bub I edited my question.

Comment: Can unsubscribed be zero? Didn't you mean "0000-00-00"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BETWEEN` statement to query a range of dates.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE date BETWEEN '1/1/2016' AND '1/31/2016'
```